# What happens in NodeJS if I call response.end() without providing any headers or data?

Tags: node.js

What happens in NodeJS if I call response.end() as soon as I receive a request without supplying any data, calling response.write(), or calling response.writeHead()? I'm curious about the answer from two angles:

1) the server angle - does this essentially take something off of a backend stack or heap within nodeJS that frees up some resources? or does something entirely different happen?

2) the client perspective - If this is coming from an ajax request that doesn't expect to receive any data in response, can any problems arise?

Comment: Have you tried? This is easy enough to find out, isn't it?

Comment: I guess what I meant (at least with part 2) is can it cause any problems? In the network section of the JavaScript Console in Google Chrome, nothing shows up (expected) and the request is not pending. This leads me to believe that in Google Chrome specifically, there won't be any issues as a result of doing this. But will this be the same for all other browsers? My webapp runs using Canvas, so only HTML5 compliant browsers will ever be able to run into this situation, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) All resources associated with the request and response are relinquished (made available for garbage collection)

2) node sends out a response with default headers and an empty body. It's purely up to the client how to deal with that. In most cases, the client will regard the default headers as incomplete, but in the absence of a response body, there's no alternative.

Answer (score 6):

The obvious thing to do here, is just to try it. Node.js code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.end();
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

From the server perspective it's not different to adding data / custom headers in there.

From client perspective, gives me empty response body, with headers:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Sun, 29 Jul 2012 07:58:51 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

The difference to the [hello world example](http://nodejs.org#column1) is that `Content-Type` header is missing and the response body is empty and that's it.